# Motioneye on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: raspberry-pi, motion-detection

I've installed Motioneye on a Raspberry Pi Zero and connected a camera.  I can get it to detect motion, and take an image in response to detected motion.  Unfortunately, images are being saved to the target directory as root, rather than user.  I'm hoping for suggestions to have motion save them to as user.

I've followed the instruction here:  [Running Motioneye as Normal User](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneye/wiki/Running-As-Normal-User)

I have another script that is running as user, so it can not manipulate these files.  I know I could have that script run as root, but that seems like a generally bad idea.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The question might be better suited to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com as it does not seem specifically programming related.

Comment: If you run `chmod g+s DIRECTORY` on the directory where the images are saved, the group of the directory is propagated to all directories and files subsequently created within it. So, if you find your own group and `chown` the directory to that group, all created files will be accessible to you.